# It is experimentaly true that a material keep with same temperature at fusion?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

If I have some amount of ice, and I give to it heat in order to turn it to water (and by the relations in thermodynamics we expect that an specific amount of heat is sufficient and necessary to transforms ice on water).

If experimentally we give the mentioned quantity of energy, we really get an system at the end of procedure that is only water with 0°C?

There is some article that can I read?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will put energy into the system and the temperature will stay the same. This energy is needed for the crystal structure to be dissolved. I grant you that it is a strange thought indeed!

In a microscopic scale, the energy of each particle is not the same. If you take liquid water at room temperature, not every single molecule will have the same kinetic energy. That is distributed according to the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution. Macroscopic quantities like the temperature only have a meaning when averaged over many many particles.

Cold ice is not completely solid. There are a couple of molecules which are “liquid”. The quotation marks are because a single particle has no phase in this sense. Single molecules can get stuck to the crystal or break free from it. The important thing is that the probability of breaking free will become smaller and smaller when the temperature decreases. At the melting point the chance of breaking free and getting stuck is the same. So you can change the system by inserting heat and make more molecules break free.